# Pointcut expression issues in Logging, Spring AOP with log4j

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have to apply logging info for all the methods belonging to package and sub-packages for com.mycomp.** .I have tried lots of pointcuts given in spring reference manual but sadly no one is working out for me.
I am using

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mycomp..(..))")
private void businessService() {}  // signature
```

what I am getting is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting
'name pattern cannot finish with ..' at character position 27
 execution(* com.mycomp..(..))
```

In the documentation it is given that

```
 @Pointcut("execution( com.xyz.someapp..service..(..))")
```

I have tried using execution(com.mycomp..(..)) but got a similar Exception.

On using the pointcut @Around(value="execution(* xyz.package.foo.bar..*(..))")  as suggested by James I am getting new kind of exception  when I starting the server.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy76 implementing org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.mycompname.BancsContextAware] for property 'bancsContextAware': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
... 57 more
```

Later on debugging I found out that in one of the classes I was using object.getClass().getAnnotation() and the proxy object which is created by spring AOP does not have annotation. Because of that only I was getting a null pointer exception. I sorted that using AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(someObject) 
but now the problem is that I have some final classes and enum inside sub-packages of com.mycom.. because of this I am getting

```
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.mycom.util.BancsServiceProvider]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.mycom.util.BancsServiceProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
```

So how to exclude final classes and enum from Spring AOP pointcut.

Answer (score 2):

The pointcut and method you are looking for is something like this:

```
@Around(value="execution(* xyz.package.foo.bar..*(..))")
public Object beforeAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    //Get log4j logger for target class.
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(jp.getTarget().getClass());

    logger.info(jp.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " " + jp.getSignature().getName() + " "
            + "Hit:");
    Object returnVal = jp.proceed(jp.getArgs());
    logger.info(jp.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " " + jp.getSignature().getName() + " "
            + "Finished:");
    return returnVal;
}
```

The above code will log the class and method name as well as 'Hit' before it enters the method and 'Finished' once it is done in the following manner:

```
xyz.package.foo.bar.service.getPerson: Hit:
xyz.package.foo.bar.dao.getPerson: Hit:
xyz.package.foo.bar.dao.getPerson: Finished:
xyz.package.foo.bar.service.getPerson: Finished:
...
```

If you want to try to follow multithreaded execution of methods, just use the following:

```
@Around(value="execution(* xyz.package.foo.bar..*(..))")
public Object beforeAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(jp.getTarget().getClass());

    String executionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    logger.info(jp.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " " + jp.getSignature().getName() + " "
            + "Hit:" + executionId);
    Object returnVal = jp.proceed(jp.getArgs());
    logger.info(jp.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " " + jp.getSignature().getName() + " "
            + "Finished:" + executionId);
    return returnVal;
}
```

You will get a UUID per threaded invocation and this will allow you to track how fast these methods are executing across all your threads. I use this code when trying to get method times for performance testing and it works wonders.

Make sure you have the class this is declared in as an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

@Pointcut("within(com.mycomp..*)")